# Node.js post request returns 404

Tags: node.js, postman

i'm trying to use postman with "post" method , but when i use it i'm getting a 404 not found error.

i will attach my code and a picture of the error
thanks in advance

**using React Native**

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    res.send('You made a post request');
});

module.exports = router;
```

[Picture from Postman app with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emXbJ.png)

Comment: I dont understand your question..are you using express in react native to make api calls?? Why aren't you using Fetch API mate... 
Correct me if i am not getting your problem

Comment: where you start nodejs server?

Answer (score -1):

Things to consider are 
 1. Make sure you have imported the routes in app.js and used them.
 2. Your app is running on 3000 port.

```
const UserRouter = require('./routes/v1');
app.use('/api',UserRouter);
 const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function() {
console.log("listening at port",port)
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering,
in a weird way its now working, i actually didnt do a thing